# Pennylane variational classifier demo - need for padding

Tags: quantum-algorithms, vqe, machine-learning, pennylane, variational-quantum-algorithms

In the [variational classifier demo from Pennylane](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_variational_classifier), the data loading is performed with

```
data = np.loadtxt("variational_classifier/data/iris_classes1and2_scaled.txt")
X = data[:, 0:2]
print("First X sample (original)  :", X[0])

# pad the vectors to size 2^2 with constant values
padding = 0.3 * np.ones((len(X), 1))
X_pad = np.c_[np.c_[X, padding], np.zeros((len(X), 1))]
print("First X sample (padded)    :", X_pad[0])

# More code following...
```

Why are the 2 feature data from the IRIS dataset padded to make 4 features before calculating the angles? What is the significance of this padding?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not create these "latent dimensions" with padding, the normalisation of the input vector looses all information on the length of the input. Decision boundaries would therefore have a very simplistic, radial shape like shown here:

[image]

With padding, the normalisation implicitly writes information about the length into the added dimensions and decision boundaries can be a bit more interesting.

For some datasets padding might not be important, but in the simple example used in the demo the classifier would probably not learn very well.